# How to show how many records in django databes I have?

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem. In my models.py file I have two classes: 
class Categories and class Websites.
In Categories by the admin panel I added many records of categories. How to show in html file for example : how many webstites were added in the category 'Company' or in the another categories?

Comment: Post your models to make the question more clear

Answer (score 0):

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Kategorie(models.Model):
    glowna = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Kategoria')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Kategoria'
        verbose_name_plural='Kategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.glowna


class Witryna(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(default="", max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Nazwa strony')
    adres_www = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Adres www')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Przyjazny adres url')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Adres e-mail')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=3000, verbose_name='Opis strony')
    kategoria = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    data_publikacji = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data publikacji')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Strona www'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony www'

    def publikacja(self):
        self.data_publikacji=timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa
```